# Get values by POST in Restlet framework

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm tring to get the parameters sent by POST using the [Restlet framework](http://restlet.org/) but I can't find the way.

Here's what I have working with GET:

```
   @Get
   public StringRepresentation represent() {
      String search = getQuery().getValues("search");
      String folder = getQuery().getValues("folder");

      LinkedHashMap<String, String> list = search(search, folder);
      return new StringRepresentation(JSONObject.toJSONString(list), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   }
```

What should I do to get the data from POST?

**Update**
Still having troubles getting the 415 `Unsupported Media Type` after trying this:

```
   @Post("json")
   public StringRepresentation represent(Representation entity) {
       final Form form = new Form(entity);
       String name = form.getFirstValue("search");

      return new StringRepresentation(name, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   }
```

For more information, I'm making the POST request through PHP by using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php).

**Update 2**
By removing the `("json")` I don't get the error message anymore but the `name` variable is empty.

**Update 3**
This is the PHP code I'm using:

```
public function restful(){
    $result = $this->callAPI('POST', 'http://localhost:8182/xxxx', array('search'=> 'demo', 'folder' => 'xxxxxx'));
    print_r($result);
    die();
}


// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

public function callAPI($method, $url, $data = false){
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data){
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data){
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
            }
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $curl_response;
}
```

Comment: Maybe using "@Post" instead of "@Get"? Or Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I've tried that already, but it seems not to be enough. I get a message saying `Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: Error type 415? A lot of people have same issue...can you detail better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
@Post("json")
public void someMethod(Representation rep){...}
```

You can substitute json for the content type you can handle.

If the post is from a simple html form then you can get the Form object from the representation and extract the parameters from that.

```
@Post
public void someMethod(Representation entity){
  final Form form = new Form(entity);
  String name = form.getFirstValue("name"));
}
```

Note you can also construct Form objects from query strings.

Comment: And how I get the parameters then?

Comment: Still having the same problem. I'm updating my question with what I'm trying right now after your response.

Comment: Have you tried it without the ("json")?  That should take any post.  What are you posting?

Comment: without the `(json)` i dont get the error message anymore, but the variable name is empty.

Comment: You need to debug out what Restlet thinks its receiving.  Its not a standard form, nor is it json (or the json handler would have caught it)

Comment: You need to debug out what Restlet thinks its receiving.  Its not a standard form, nor is it json (or the json handler would have caught it).  Post up the PHP code that you're using.

Comment: If I print the content of entity I get `[multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------0d74cce170d6]`

Comment: Finally the problem was on the way I was sending the variables by POST through PHP. IT shouldn't be in an array but in an string of the type `param1=value&param2=value2`. I will accept this answer as you helped me to reach to the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample, I was wondering what happened to `getEntityAsForm()` when upgrading from restlet 1 to 2.